# Cant start VNC without display

Tags: ssh, window-manager, android, vnc

I have a strange problem. Im running debian on Android  with Linux Deploy. I can work with terminal . I use Juice Ssh to connect to a terminal. I have installed Icewm window manager . When i start Icewm it gives the following error .

root@localhost:/home/joe# icewm
IceWM: Can't open display: . X must be running and $DISPLAY set.

What is wrong? Why is it happening? And what can i do in order to fix it ?
Thanks in advance .
[image: Juice Ssh screen]

Comment: As the error message says, is $DISPLAY set? `echo $DISPLAY` should provide some sort of feedback. It sounds like X is running but not properly configured.

Comment: >> root@localhost:/home/joe# echo $Display >> root@localhost:/home/joe#

Comment: I think there is definitely something wrong with X. Check your system messages/logs for errors and warnings with X. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in troubleshooting X... FWIW, here is what mine looks like on a couple systems: http://imgur.com/a/FsHL9

Answer (score 0):

Does your Android thing actually support running X or is it just terminal-based?

If `echo $DISPLAY` shows that it's unset, X is not running, or your terminal is unaware of it.